# How can I display the description value of a query parameter in a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

If I have defined a query parameter that has a translated value, i.e. the user is prompted with a list of "readable" values and these are converted into the actual value before being used in the SQL query.

Now I want to display the used query parameters in the report header, but I can only figure out how to get the actual, used value (the "translated one") and not the readable one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the "readable" parameters converted before being passed to Crystal? Or are they being converted withing crystal?

Comment: This is actually within Crystal. It's not called externally so the report is called and executed within Crystal (actually on Crystal Server 2011). The parameters are converted before being passed to the query, so the "human readable" text is only shown in the query parameter GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get the 'readable' values from the parameter field, unfortunately.

If the values (keys and text) are from a table, you could create a subreport, linked to the parameter field, that returns the text values and serializes them.  Place the subreport in its own section to allow for expansion; you may also need to experiment w/ section underlays.

If the values are static, you can create a formula field w/ a CASE statement to convert the key to a friendly value.

Comment: Thanks! That essentially answers my question - there is no magic function that can look up the "readable" value, and I'll have to code around it.

Comment: Is there an example of this with pictures anywhere? I'm working with a SQL command as a data-source and I wonder if this is somehow throwing my attempts at this off. I would like to see if I'm linking the sub report and placing it correctly. When you say place the subreport in it's own section, does it need to be a detail section, or a grouper section or is this irrelevant?

Comment: I would recommend the Report Header section (because I only want the subreport generated once) for my answer, but you can you any section that you want.